# Missing "Send to compressed folder" option. Anyway to restore?

Tags: windows-10, zip

Prior to Windows 10, there was a "Send to compressed folder" in the File Explorer. Is this really no longer there? Any secret switch to turn it back on?

Not a fan of installing 3rd party hacky utilities that "integrate" into the shell.

It's funny that I can send to a "fax recipient" but can't compress.

Anyway, I looked at a registry addition that attempts to resolve this, but it failed to install:

http://www.technipages.com/windows-compressed-file-option-missing-from-send-menu

Other options?

Comment: Its there as usual in all my Win 10 installs.. so it's not "normal" that it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `C:\Users\<profile_name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`. You will have to enable show hidden items to drill to it, otherwise just copy and paste the whole path into *File Explorer*, with correct *profile_name* of course.

Most likely, you'll see all of the usual *SendTo* options here. If you see two related to Bluetooth, delete the one that has a size of 0B.  This will correct the problem. In my case, the one I deleted was simply *Bluetooth*, while the correct one that I kept was *Bluetooth device*.

If you don't see anything in this folder, copy everything from `C:\Users\Default \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` into the same folder for your profile.